# SQL WHERE with LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table1

```
ColA       ColB     ColC
A          1        X
```

Table2

```
ColA     ColB     ColD          ColE
A        1        1/1/2017      No
A        1        1/2/2017      Yes
A        1        1/3/2017      Yes
```

Desired Output:

```
A     1      X     1/2/2017
```

Looking for earliest date where E = "Yes".

Tried

```
SELECT Table1.ColA, Table1.ColB, Table1.ColC, min(Table2.ColD) as ColD
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ColA=Table2.ColA AND Table1.ColB=Table2.ColB
WHERE Table2.ColE="Yes"
GROUP BY Table1.ColA, Table1.ColB, Table1.ColC
```

But I found a record in Table1 where ColB was null.  That record was not included in the results.  ColE in this case is a text field.

Trying to figure out why rows from Table1 are being omitted in this query - looking to keep Table1 intact, just add columns from Table2 where applicable.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me and your data makes no sense. I'd suggest you edit your question to describe the data a little better and [format your SQL](http://poorsql.com/). Also, change the table and column names to be slightly less abstract than `Table1.ColA`. Maybe `People` and `Birthdays` or something.

Comment: In your SQL query, try replacing `LEFT JOIN` with `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(This is tagged as msaccess, I'm not completely sure on how it compares null, so someone please edit me if I'm off on that regard. I'm going with what most databases would do with nulls, and some quick googling makes me think this is the correct approach.)*

The join is goofy as @wind39 alluded to in the comments. You've got a WHERE on the optional (right hand) table, so this becomes effectively an inner join. Did you mean a RIGHT outer join? Or do you want something more like this?

```
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ColA=Table2.ColA 
    AND (Table1.ColB=Table2.ColB 
    OR (Table1.ColB is null AND Table2.ColB is null))
WHERE Table2.ColE="Yes"
```

I.e. Give me everything from Table1 and Table2 where they match on ColA and also match on ColB unless Table1.ColB and Table2.ColB are both null. Many databases won't directly equate Null to itself, that's why there's the AND for the "is null" checks and is likely the source of your issue.

If you really want everything from Table1, but only those rows from Table2 where ColE="Yes", then you can't have that WHERE clause. It will filter the FINAL results of Table1*Table2, not just the rows on the Table2 join. One thing you could do is move it to the LEFT JOIN clause.

```
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ColA=Table2.ColA 
    AND (Table1.ColB=Table2.ColB 
    OR (Table1.ColB is null AND Table2.ColB is null))
    AND Table2.ColE="Yes"
```

Depending on your data, there may be a different correct solution as the rules for when ColB is null aren't apparent from your question.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed reply, that helps a lot!  Scenario 2 is exaclty right - I want all records from Table1.  Unfortunately (I'm using Access) when I add the last statement Table2.ColE="Yes" I get an error.  "JOIN expression not supported"

Comment: Disregard last comment, putting parentheses around the whole expression fixed the error.  It returned the exact right # of rows - appears I'm in business, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question, "Trying to figure out why rows from Table1 are being omitted in this query" is simply because you're joining on both columns A and B.  If ColB is NULL in Table1, it's not going to match up against any records in Table2 with what I see in your sample data, and therefore that record won't be returned.

Comment: How do I include all records from Table1?  Table1 has 300K records, Table2 600k - would like output to have 300k with appropriate additional columns from Table 2.  My output right now is 90K.

Comment: You're basing your join on Table1, and then adding a WHERE clause that references Table2.  You're not going to return every record from Table1 with that WHERE clause the way it is.  Your sample is a bit abstract, it's hard to tell what is exactly wrong with the logic.  If you could post a few records of actual data it'd be much easier to line up your logic.